# React image from public folder not loading in Docker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, docker

I am running a Node server and React frontend in Docker. They have a shared volume, specifically for the /public folder. At Docker build time, the only relevant picture in the /public folder is "output1.png".

During runtime, the server receives images and writes them to the volume, e.g. "input1.png".

I can see both of these files (input1.png, output1.png) in the docker filesystem for both containers: [image], and when I pull input1.png off of the docker volume, it's a valid image (in fact, it is the same image as output1.png).

However, when I go to show these images in React, output1.png shows up but input1.png does not. I'm not that familiar with webdev, but another data point that might be helpful is that localhost:3000/output1.png shows an image whereas localhost:3000/input1.png does not. I'm wondering if this is an issue with using Docker, like maybe only files that are there during the build are valid in the javascript runtime considered?

Server image saving code:

```
//  a zmq subscriber that reads from zmq and publishes over websocket to react.
//  react apps can't directly read from zmq, so we need to use this server to bridge the gap.

// zmq subscriber initialized here
var zmq = require("zeromq"),
  sock = zmq.socket("sub");

// ws server initialized here to send data to react
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 6002 });
let currentData = {};

let count = 0;
sock.bindSync(`tcp://*:6001`, (err) => { // bind fails because we don't wait for bind or smth, bindSync works
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(`ZeroMQ publisher bound to port 6001`);
});sock.subscribe("");
console.log("Subscriber connected to port 6001");

sock.on('message', function(message) {
    try {
        count += 1;
        currentData = JSON.parse(message);
        const image_count = { type: 'image_count', value: count };
        currentData.push(image_count);
        wss.clients.forEach(function each(client) {
            if (client.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
                client.send(JSON.stringify(currentData));
            }
        });
        const fs = require('fs');
        const imageObject = currentData.find(item => item.type === 'composite_image');
        const image_rcvd = Buffer.from(imageObject.image, 'base64');
        const filename = `public/input${count}.png`;
        fs.writeFile(filename, image_rcvd, function(err) {
          if (err) {
            console.log('Error:', err);
          } else {
            console.log('Image saved');
          }
        });
        currentData = currentData.filter(item => item.type !== 'composite_image'); // Remove the "composite_image" object
        console.log(currentData);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error parsing ZMQ message:', error);
    }
});

// ws server connection
wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
    console.log('WebSocket client connected');

    ws.on('close', function close() {
        console.log('WebSocket client disconnected');
    });
});

console.log("WebSocket server started on ws://0.0.0.0:6002");
```

Relevant image placing code (leaflet map):

```js
if (imageData.image_count !== 0) {
      console.log("adding image");
      let filename = process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/input" + imageData.image_count + ".png";
      console.log(filename);
      try {
        let overlay = L.imageOverlay.rotated(filename, imageData.topleft, imageData.topright, imageData.bottomleft).addTo(map);
        console.log(overlay);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
```

React dockerfile:

```
# react
FROM node:14
WORKDIR /app


COPY package.json .
COPY package-lock.json .

RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g serve

COPY . .
RUN npm run build
# server on 3001
EXPOSE 3001
CMD ["serve", "-s", "build", "-l", "3001"]
```

Node server dockerfile:

```
# server
FROM node:14
WORKDIR /app


COPY package.json .
COPY package-lock.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .
RUN npm run build

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

Comment: Can we also see the server code that serves these assets? That's likely where the issue is.

Comment: @adsy added, I thought since the file was saved it should be fine but maybe you're right

Comment: Sorry its the "serving" code, rather than the "saving" code I'm interested in. What code actually makes these images available over HTTP?

Comment: @adsy Sorry I'm not too well versed, here is how I understand what is happening in my system: I have a websocket connection between the backend and frontend. The server saves the file to the public folder, then informs the react frontend of the new file. This is all done locally on the localhost and isn't meant to see production ever. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Putting it another way: something, somewhere is actually making the contents of the public folder available to the browser. Something is configured somewhere to say "anything in public folder is available on localhost".

Comment: @adsy  It seems like the public folder is special: "The public folder is a special folder in your React application that is not processed by Webpack. This means that any files that you put in the public folder will be served directly to the browser, without being bundled up with the rest of your application."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256770/discussion-between-kevinlinxc-and-adsy).

Answer (score 0):

The solution, which adsy guided me to, was to share the /app/build volume instead of /app/public between the docker containers. The build directory is where the files are actually retrieved from at runtime. Scuffed solution because I am saving to the build directory at run time, but it works for me and that's all that matters.